# SQL Server: pair of IDs which has the same elements on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm working with SQL Server 2005.

I have a table `INVENTORY` with columns `ProductId, BranchId, Stock`

I want to select the pairs of `BranchId` which have the exactly the same products.

For example

```
BranchId - ProductId
1 - a
1 - b
1 - c
2 - b
2 - c
3 - a
3 - b
3 - c
```

Must return the tuple

```
Inventory1.BranchId - Inventory2.BranchId
1 - 3
3 - 1
```

Does not mater if a pair is duplicated in two tuples (1-3 and 3-1).

The idea is:

```
SELECT I1.BranchId,I1.ProductId,I2,BranchId,I2.ProductId
FROM inventory AS I1,inventory as I2
WHERE I1.BranchId<>I2.BranchId AND
"I1.ProductId's Exists in the products list of I2" //This is the part I don't know how to do
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: its still `unclear` about what are you are asking ?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this by using CTEs. The main idea is to concatenate the list of products for each branch and then to join this CTE with itself:

```
WITH InventoryCTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        I1.BranchId
        , STUFF(
           (SELECT
                ', ' + I2.ProductId
                FROM Inventory I2
                WHERE I1.BranchId = I2.BranchId
                ORDER BY I2.ProductId
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
           ).value('.','varchar(max)')
           ,1,2, ''
            ) AS ProductIds
    FROM Inventory I1
    GROUP BY I1.BranchId
)
SELECT I1.BranchId, I2.BranchId, I2.ProductIds
FROM
    InventoryCTE I1
    INNER JOIN InventoryCTE I2 ON I2.ProductIds = I1.ProductIds
WHERE I1.BranchId != I2.BranchId
```